# update multiple form fields from inputs with a click of a button using java

Tags: javascript

I want to update multiple form fields from multiple inputs with the click a button.  Here is the start of the code:

```
<form id="frmFive9">
    <div>
        <i>
            <span lang=EN-US style='font-size:14.0pt;line-height:
            115%;color:black;background:yellow;'>
                <strong>
                     IF CASH - CLICK SET TO CASH:
                </strong>
            </span>
        </i>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="button" onclick="UpdatePaymentType('Cash')" value="Set to Cash">
```

I would also like to update the Payment Amount, Base Amount and Upsell Amount from inputs.  Is this feasible to do this in javascript?

Comment: If course it is.  You can modify the HTML elements and values however you like.  How are you *trying* to update them?

Comment: Please post the code of `UpdatePaymentType()` as well as the HTML of the inputs you want to manipulate.

Comment: @Ramy is 100% right, can do anything you looking to do but there is not enough information to help you

Comment: <input name="z_amount" value="0" type="money"><br /><br />

Comment: <input name="z_amount" value="0" type="money">                   
<input type="radio" name="y_amount" value="0" checked>$0<br />
<input type="radio" name="y_amount" value="10">$10<br />            
<input type="radio" name="y_amount"value="15">$15 
x_amount is a result of a function that sums up y_amount and z_amount

Answer (score 0):

you should look into jQuery as this will be a good thing for you to learn and will simplify any manipulation you want.

a simple jQuery example would be something like

```
if($('#IdOfInputWithValueToMakeChoiceWith').val() === "SomthingToCompareTo")
{
    $('#IdOfAControlToChange').val('new value');
}
```

starting there you can based on what you are looking to do, google anything you are trying to manipulate and how you are trying to change it and should find what you are looking for.

want more help then we need more info.

Hope this helps